# Can you explain how this Factorial function works?

Tags: javascript

I understand that "a" solution is:

```js
function Factorial(number)
{
    if(number == 0 || number == 1){
        return 1;
    }

    return number * Factorial(number -1);

}
```

I want to understand what exactly is going on.  I understand what is going on all the way to the last part when number == 1.

If we were to take a simple example of say 3!

1. 3 is not equal to 0 or 1 so we return 3 * Factorial(2)
2. 2 is not equal to 0 or 1 so we return 2 * Factorial(1)
3. 1 is equal to 1 so we return 1

How do we know when to stop? Is it the fact that we return 1 that tells the function to stop?

If that is the case, why does the function not stop when we first return 3 * Factorial(2)?  Is it because it's returning a function so that it must continue until it no longer returns a function?

Thank you

Comment: "Is it because it's returning a function so that it must continue until it no longer returns a function?"  <- Precisely

Comment: Do note that this function creates an infinite loop when not called with a positive whole number.

Comment: The *last* thing that happens is that 3 is multiplied by the value returned from `Factorial(2)`. That's the ultimate returned value. That step cannot happen until `Factorial(2)` is finished, and `Factorial(2)` can't finish until `Factorial(1)` finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to understand the logic of factorial.

So factorial is just products, indicated by an exclamation mark ie, if you write

```
 0! = 1
 1! = 1
 2! = 2*1
 3! = 3*2*1
 4! = 4*3*2*1
 5! = 5*4*3*2*1
```

Hope you find the pattern, so you can write the above factorials as:

```
 0! = 1
 1! = 1
 2! = 2*1!
 3! = 3*2!
 4! = 4*3!
 5! = 5*4!
```

So in your function you are using the similar logic.

Now in your function

```
if(number == 0 || number == 1)
{
   return 1;
}
```

The above logic is to cover the first two cases i.e, **0!** and **1!** And

```
return number * Factorial(number -1);
```

is for the rest of the numbers.

So you are using the recursive technique of solving the factorial problem.

To understand recursion, lets take a number say 5 i.e., we want find the value of 5!.

Then first your function will check

```
if(number == 0 || number == 1)
```

which is not satisfied, then it moves to the next line ie,

```
return number * Factorial(number -1);
```

which gives

```
5*Factorial(5-1) which is equal to 5*Factorial(4)
```

Now on subsequent calls to your Factorial function it will return the value like below:

```
5*(4*Factorial(4-1)) which is equal to 5*(4*Factorial(3))
5*(4*(3*Factorial(3-1)) which is equal to 5*(4*(3*Factorial(2)))
5*(4*(3*(2*Factorial(2-1)))) which is equal to 5*(4*(3*(2*Factorial(1))))
```

Now when it returns factorial(1) then your condition

```
if(number == 0 || number == 1)
```

is satisfied and hence you get the result as:

```
5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

**On a side note:**

Beware that factrial is used only for **positive integers**.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion relies on what is called a base case:

```
if(number == 0 || number == 1){
    return 1;
}
```

That `if` statement is called your base case. The base case defines when the recursion should stop. Note how you are returning `1` not returning the result of a call to the function again such as `Factorial(number -1)`

If the conditions for your base case are not met (i.e. if `number` is NOT 1 or 0) then you proceed to call the function again with `number * Factorial(number - 1)`

Answer (score 2):

> If that is the case, why does the function not stop when we first return 3 * Factorial(2)?

Your simple example of 3! can be elaborated like this :

```
return 3 * Factorial(2)
```

will then be replaced by

```
return 3 * (2 * Factorial(1))
```

which then will be replaced by

```
return 3 * (2 * 1) // = 6 Hence 6 is returned at last and recursion ends.
```

> How do we know when to stop?

When all your Factorial(value) is replaced by a returned value we stop.

> Is it the fact that we return 1 that tells the function to stop?

In a way, yes. Because it is the last returned value.

Comment: Best answer for understanding what gets

Answer (score 1):

It is called recursion.

This function is called like this

var result = Factorial(3);
in Factorial function

First time 
    return 3*Factorial(2);

Now here return statement doesnt get executed insted Factorial is called again..
so second time
  return 2*Factorial(1);

again in Factorial(1)
Third time 
  return 1;

So go to second 
 return 2*1;

Next to first
  return 3*(2*1);

Finally
var result = 3*2*1 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

The function is recursing (calling itself) - and taking one from "number" each time.

Eventually (as long as its a positive integer you call it with, otherwise you'll probably get an infinite loop) you'll always hit the condition (number == 1) so instead of recursing further, it'll return 1 rather than call the function again.

Then, once you have hit the bottom (1), it'll start to run the function and work back up the other way along the function call stack, using the previous result each time:

```
1 = 1 
(2*1) = 2
(3*2) = 6
(4*6) = 24
```

etc

So the final return statement from the function will return the required result