# What happen behind when this block of js code run?

Tags: javascript

This javaScript code block is making me crazy,that how it is doing the computation behind. I try to manually do it with calculator but the results start to be different at 4. Please explain  if you know how

```
function fac(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return fac(n - 1) * n;
}


if i run console.log(fac(1));

// > 1

if i run console.log(fac(2));

// > 2

if i run console.log(fac(3));

// > 6
```

i was thinking this is what was happening behind

```
(2-1) * 2 = 2, 
(3-1) * 3 = 6,
```

until i put

```
(4-1) * 4 = 12.

if i run console.log(fac(4)); the output is 24 not 12  


// > 24 how and why?
```

cheers

Comment: It is performing recursive function call. For 4 => 4 * (4 - 1) * (3 - 1) * 1

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544955/can-you-explain-how-this-factorial-function-works?

Comment: Oops, i missed one. For 4 => 4 * (4 - 1) * (3 - 1) * (2 - 1) * 1

Answer (score 1):

It is performing recursive function call to the same function.

```
function fac(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return fac(n - 1) * n;
}

fac(4);
```

- Value of `n` is 4. So it should return`fac(4 - 1) * 4)`. Now `fac(4 -1)` is calculated before returning the value.
- Value of `n` is 3. Now it will return `fac(3 - 1) * 3)`, which replaces `fac(4 - 1)` in previous statement. So, it will become `fac(3 - 1) * 3 * 4`.
- Value of `n` is 2. Now it will return `fac(2 - 1) * 2)`, which replaces `fac(3 - 1)` in previous statement. So, it will become `fac(2 - 1) * 2 * 3 * 4`.
- Value of `n` is 1. Now it will return `fac(1 - 1) * 1)`, which replaces `fac(2 - 1)` in previous statement. So, it will become `fac(1 - 1) * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4`.
- Value of `n` is 0. Now it will return `1`, which replaces `fac(1 - 1)` in previous statement. So, it will become `1 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4`.

As you can see, you can avoid multiplying by `1` twice by changing your code to

```
function fac(n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fac(n - 1) * n;
}
```

In short,

```
function fac(n) {
    return (n == 1) ? 1 : (fac(n - 1) * n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a factorial. It's calculates all permutation a set with n elements has. Or simpler:

> [factorial] is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n.

[Wikipedia:Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

It's noted as `n!`. For example:

```
1! = 1 
2! = 1 * 2 = 2
3! = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6
4! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
```

What the function is doing is recursively calling itself. When you execute the function `fac(4)` the following happens:

At `fac(4)`, since `4 != 0` the value returned is `fac(4 -1) * 4`. However, since the return function contains a reference to a function, we wait for it to return a value.

At `fac(3)` (i.e. `fac(4-1)`), since `3 != 0` the value returned is `fac(3-1) * 3`. However same thing happens and we wait for result of `fac(3-1)`/`fac(2)`.

At `fac(2)` (i.e. `fac(3-1)`) since `2 != 0` the value returned is `fac(2-1) * 2`. Again, since we are calling a function we wait for its return until we proceed will calculation.

At `fac(1)` (i.e. `fac(2-1)`) since `1 != 0` the value returned is `fac(1-1)* 1` and we defer for `fac(1-1)` to return result.

At `fac(0)` (i.e. `fac(1-1)`) since `0==0` we return value one which is neutral for multiplication.

In `fac(1)`, `fac(1-1)` becomes one, so `fac(1)` value becomes `1*1` or `1`.

In `fac(2)`, `fac(2-1)` is replaced with `1` so `fac(2)` becomes `1*2` or `2`.

In `fac(3)`, `fac(3-1)` is replaced with `2`, and `fac(3)` becomes `2*3` or `6`.

In `fac(4)`, `fac(4-1)` is repalced with `6` and `fac(4)` becomes `6*4` or `24`.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate - wikipedia link is helpful thanks Fath